# Enabling kube-ovn in the running Microk8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I am running a microk8s cluster with 3 master and 5 worker nodes. I need to enable `kube-ovn` addon but the [document](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-kube-ovn) says to enable the addon before running the `microk8s join...` command.

My question is what happens if I run it in the running cluster? I do not want to messed up my cluster so asking.

> Cluster considerations
>
> For MicroK8s clusters, ensure that the KubeOVN addon is enabled on all
> nodes before joining the cluster:
>
> microk8s enable kube-ovn microk8s join ...

Comment: Hi \`prabhat\` are your queries addressed if you are still facing some issues revert back here..

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further

Answer (score 0):

In general, microk8s deployment comes along with calico CNI enabled. When we try to change the network plugin from calico CNI to kube-ovn, the calico plugin will be removed first and kube-ovn plugin will be installed. This is mentioned in the **[official document](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-kube-ovn#:%7E:text=This%20will%20remove%20the%20calico%20CNI%2C%20deploy%20the%20OVN%20data%20plane%20services%20on%20the%20cluster%2C%20and%20then%20configure%20the%20KubeOVN%20CNI%20for%20the%20cluster.)** which you have shared in the description. Since there will be changes happening to network components if you run this command on a running cluster, pods might get restarted or crashed which will result in the downtime.